# Anyone wanna design some xenosophonts together?

Tags: aliens, hard-science, culture, interspecies-relations, species

I’m Campbell and I’m looking to create a science fiction universe. I’m 18, and I’m returning to writing and relearning a lot of things. But I’d love to make some friends and create an alien species together with someone.

Comment: Probably you will have some success on https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! This is a Q&A site focusing exclusively on answering specific questions, though, and not really a message board, so I have to vote to close because this is off topic. But there are way to have this discussion - either the chat or using the Sandbox in the Meta are both good ways of doing so. I threw you an upvote so you can enter the chat now.

Comment: Also consider using our primary chat room, [The Factory Floor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor).